# How to autowire class field before calling factory-method?

Tags: java, spring

I've got a troubles with using @autowired annotation because of structure of project... I have class that should be a bean with singleton scope...

```
public class Dumper {

    public void dumpData() {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

It should be used in some other class

```
public class DataStore {

    @Autowired
    Dumper dumper;
}
```

but DataDource class is already used in other class that used factory-method=getInst
so it's initialiazed before like this

```
public class Singleton {
    @Autowired
    DataStore ds;
    Dao dao;
    getInst () {
        dao = Dao(ds);
//other stuff
    }
}
```

so when I use @autowired to ds dao hasn't instance of ds... And create dao like bean - invoke a lot of situations like this... Is there anybody knows is there in spring some tool to autowire field of class before calling factory-method?

Comment: You aren't wiring anything you are constructing a new `DataStore` yourself.

Comment: I write code here before wiring, obviously I stacked with a problems after using @Autowired for DataStore in Singleton... if I extract dao = new Dao(ds) to PostConstruct could it help me in this situation?

Comment: No it will never work because you aren't using autowiring for the DataStore. You are creating an instance yourself which isn't managed by spring which basically makes the `@Autowired` useless.

Comment: Oh god! I've told u - I use autowire, but here i wright old code code `public class Singleton {

    DataStore ds = new DataStore();
    Dao dao;
    getInst () {
        dao = Dao(ds);
    }
}` 
now this code using 
`public class Singleton {
@Autowired
    DataStore ds;
    Dao dao;
    getInst () {
        dao = Dao(ds);
    }
}` and it makes troubles with initializing bead dumper before init-method

Comment: Please edit your question with your present code and present problem.

Comment: I just extract `dao = Dao(ds);` to @PostConstruct methot and it helps me... So I just answered on my question alone)))

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you write `DataStore ds = new DataStore();` none of spring initialization will occur on `ds`. You must autowire it in the class Singleton and make Singleton a spring bean. For the same reason, you should make `dao` a bean and autowire `ds` in it. If you really have good reasons not to do so, you must find an access to the `ApplicationContext` and get the beans rorm it but *never* create them by `new` (or do not use spring at all ...).

Comment: see my last comment under the question

Comment: I tired to answer that I use in my code `@Autowired DataStore ds`;

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dumper {

    public void dumpData() {
        //stuff
    }
}


public class DataStore {

    @Autowired
    Dumper dumper;
}
```

Now you should create Dao Bean,autowire the datastore in it

```
public class Singleton {

    @Autowired
    DataStore ds;
    Dao dao;
    getInst () {
        dao = Dao(ds);
    }
}
```

**Now make sure you have define your bean in configuration file with reference properly,  to avoid initialization problem.That means datastore bean is defined with dumper as its ref along with separate bean for dumper also.**